# Apache Spark group by DF, collect values into list and then group by list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Apache Spark DataFrame (**DF1**):

```
function_name | param1 | param2 | param3 | result
---------------------------------------------------
     f1       |   a    |   b    |   c    |   1        
     f1       |   b    |   d    |   m    |   0
     f2       |   a    |   b    |   c    |   0
     f2       |   b    |   d    |   m    |   0
     f3       |   a    |   b    |   c    |   1
     f3       |   b    |   d    |   m    |   1
     f4       |   a    |   b    |   c    |   0
     f4       |   b    |   d    |   m    |   0
```

First of all, I'd like to group DataFrame by `function_name`, collect results into the `ArrayType` and receive the new DataFrame (**DF2**):

```
function_name | result_list
--------------------------------
     f1       |  [1,0]
     f2       |  [0,0]
     f3       |  [1,1]
     f4       |  [0,0]
```

rigth after that, I need to collect `function_name` into `ArrayType` by grouping `result_list` and I'll receive new DataFrame like the following (**DF3**):

```
result_list |  function_name_lists
------------------------------------
    [1,0]   |   [f1]
    [0,0]   |   [f2,f4]
    [1,1]   |   [f3]
```

So, I have a question  - first of all, can I use grouping by ArrayType column in Apache Spark? If so, I can potentially have tens of millions values in `result_list` ArrayType single field. Will Apache Spark be able to group by `result_list` column in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

## Creating your data frame:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
list=[['f1','a','b','c',1],
     ['f1','b','d','m',0],
     ['f2','a','b','c',0],
     ['f2','b','d','m',0],
     ['f3','a','b','c',1],
     ['f3','b','d','m',1],
     ['f4','a','b','c',0],
      ['f4','b','d','m',0]]

df= spark.createDataFrame(list,['function_name','param1','param2','param3','result'])
df.show()

+-------------+------+------+------+------+
|function_name|param1|param2|param3|result|
+-------------+------+------+------+------+
|           f1|     a|     b|     c|     1|
|           f1|     b|     d|     m|     0|
|           f2|     a|     b|     c|     0|
|           f2|     b|     d|     m|     0|
|           f3|     a|     b|     c|     1|
|           f3|     b|     d|     m|     1|
|           f4|     a|     b|     c|     0|
|           f4|     b|     d|     m|     0|
+-------------+------+------+------+------+
```

## Grouping by function_name, then grouping by result_list(using collect_list), using order of param1,param2,param3:

```
w=Window().partitionBy("function_name").orderBy(F.col("param1"),F.col("param2"),F.col("param3"))
w1=Window().partitionBy("function_name")
df1=df.withColumn("result_list", F.collect_list("result").over(w)).withColumn("result2",F.row_number().over(w))\
.withColumn("result3",F.max("result2").over(w1))\
.filter(F.col("result2")==F.col("result3")).drop("param1","param2","param3","result","result2","result3")


df1.groupBy("result_list")\
.agg(F.collect_list("function_name").alias("function_name_list")).show()

    +-----------+------------------+
    |result_list|function_name_list|
    +-----------+------------------+
    |     [1, 0]|              [f1]|
    |     [1, 1]|              [f3]|
    |     [0, 0]|          [f2, f4]|
    +-----------+------------------+
```

For doing further anaylsis, transformation or cleaning on array type columns I would recommend you check out the new higher order functions in spark2.4 and above.

(collect_list will work for spark1.6 and above)

Higher order functions in open source:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains onwards

Databricks releases:
Link:https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html

Comment: Unfortunately these higher-order functions are not available with vanilla Spark. This is specific to Databricks :)

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list , collect_list is in the open source api for spark 2.4

Comment: All I'm saying that your link can be confusing. collect_list is available since spark 1.6. Rather put the link to the official documentation.

Comment: The other array functions like array_distinct, array_except, array_join, array_max etc can be considered as higher order functions are released in spark 2.4.. but you are right the other transform, filter higher order functions are only on databricks runtime.

Comment: I have added link to official docs too. thank for pointing it out

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi thanks for your answer! I have updated a little bit my question and added 3 new columns into DF1 - `param1 | param2 | param3`. In the collected list I'd like to preserve order of results based on param1, param2, param3 columns. So adding `.over(Window.partitionBy("function_name").orderBy("param1, param2, param3")))` will do the trick?

Comment: @alexanoid i have updated answer, do check it. it will work for as many different function_name entries as you want, as rownumber and max will only take the row with the full ordered array. I also tried with different combos of param1,2,3 and the order was successfully changing. let me know

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm just trying to understand why do you need additional result2 and result3 columns with row number inside of partition and max row number. If you don't mind, could you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: when you groupby it takes all uniques of function and aggregates, but window is aggregating step by step. so first row will only have [0] and second row will have [0,1], and if there is a third final row for that name then it will have [0,1,1]. so i am forcing it to only take the last row of the window which will have everything assembled in the array, thats why i use rownumber and max to get that last filled row. windows r different than groupby

Comment: I see now! This is a brilliant solution. Thank you very much for your help and patience!